# Regex to exclude a particular substring pattern

Tags: c#, regex

My current regex code is as beow .

```
var caption = Regex.Replace(fileImage.Caption, @"[^\w\s\(\)\.@-]", "",RegexOptions.None);
```

Here I replace special characters with empty character excluding certain special characters
Now I have a strange situation where I along with above match i need to exculde a substring of type `&#215;` where `215` can any number . Its can be a normal decimal or hexadecimal . if it is a hexadecimal number then it starts with 'x' after `&#`.

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

Think you mean this,

```
var caption = Regex.Replace(fileImage.Caption, @"(&#x?[a-f\d]+;)|[^\w\s\(\)\.@-]", "$1");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yZ9oZ5/1)

Comment: hexadecimals include `[a-f]`

Comment: This is a little bit more robust.  I added an 'OR" because the order of spaces and hex can be in any order : var caption = Regex.Replace(fileImage.Caption, @"(?!&#[xX]?[A-Fa-f\d]{1,3})|[^\w\s\(\)\.@-]", "")

Comment: it is giving #215; instead of &#215;

Comment: sorry it still removes ; from &#215;